# Python string concatenation speed

Tags: python, performance

I am testing the speed of different speed concatenation methods by concatenating the string representation from 1 to a large number(in my case, 20000000). The three methods that I am testing are:

```
import cProfile

count = 20000000

def profileWrapper(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **argv):
        pr = cProfile.Profile()
        pr.enable()
        string = f(*args, **argv)
        pr.create_stats()
        pr.print_stats()
        return string
    return wrapper

@profileWrapper
def naiveConcat():
    global count
    string = ''
    for i in xrange(count):
        string += `i`
    return string

@profileWrapper
def improvedConcat():
    global count
    string = []
    for i in xrange(count):
        string.append(`i`)
    return ''.join(string)

@profileWrapper
def fastestConcat():
    global count
    return ''.join([`i` for i in xrange(count)])

print 15 * "=", "naiveConcat", 15 * "="
naiveConcat()
print 15 * "=", "improvedConcat", 15 * "="
improvedConcat()
print 15 * "=", "fastestConcat", 15 * "="
fastestConcat()
```

I am expecting to see the improved method to be faster than the naive one, and it shouldn't' be much slower than the fastest method, but the result doesn't seem like that:

```
=============== naiveConcat ===============
         3 function calls in 3.951 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:90(create_stats)
        1    3.951    3.951    3.951    3.951 str_concat.py:18(naiveConcat)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


=============== improvedConcat ===============
         20000004 function calls in 6.990 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:90(create_stats)
        1    5.196    5.196    6.990    6.990 str_concat.py:26(improvedConcat)
 20000000    1.322    0.000    1.322    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.473    0.473    0.473    0.473 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}


=============== fastestConcat ===============
         4 function calls in 3.043 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:90(create_stats)
        1    2.539    2.539    3.043    3.043 str_concat.py:34(fastestConcat)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.504    0.504    0.504    0.504 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
```

The improved method turned out to be much slower even than the naive method!

This doesn't make sense since the naive method are creating new binding and copying the previous string along with the concatenated string character by character ON EACH ITERATION, this method should take O(n^2), which should be much slower than the other methods which are O(n).

So what makes the improved method so slow? The only reason that I can think of is the append method, but according to [this article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the append method takes O(1), so it's definitely not the reason. Then what takes so long in improvedConcat()? Thank you.

Comment: You should be more careful. You are timing "append" to but expect result for "join" only. Try a function with basic "%s%s" % (str1, str2). That's the fastest in most situations.

Comment: @cox, I do need to timing "append" because that is needed in my concatenation function, and I wrote a another function use the way you suggested, turned out it is the slowest of the four, much slower than the naive method. Maybe it is faster for concatenating only a few strings, but is not in the case of concatenating large amount of string  segments.

Comment: in this case "join" may be an option. The advantage of python/C++/... strings is that the length is cached in object properties. So for basic operations, you may have better results in python than in C. But concatenation is another beast. Wat you do is allocating/filling memory with data - type is not relevant. Maybe a cython function will be faster?

Comment: In your `fastestCount`, there is no need to use a list comprehension in your `join`. You can just use the generator expression, i.e. remove the brackets. I believe this will further improve the performance of that function for you.

Answer (score 2):

The ncalls column of improvedConcat shows that you made 20000004 function calls, compared to just a few for the other algorithms.    Function calls aren't super cheap in Python, so try to keep those limited.  To demonstrate, I made a new test following your pattern called nop, which merely calls an empty function definition:

```
def foo():
    pass

@profileWrapper
def nop():
    for i in xrange(count):
        foo()
    return ''
```

I get similar timing results to your other test, and this NOP (No Operation) test results in

```
=============== nop ===============
20000003 function calls in 4.386 seconds
```

So you've got 4.4s of overhead making function calls.

Comment: I wonder what the difference would be if OP used `string += [i]`.

Comment: @2rs2ts: "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects".   I tried some variations with map(str, array), range instead of xrange, and a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, but didn't improve on fastestConcat.

Comment: I reduce the total count to 1, `count = 1; timeit.timeit('b = improvedConcat()', setup='from __main__ import improvedConcat', number=1)`, the result still suggests that the improved method is slower: `naive: 3.40938568115e-05; improved: 4.10079956055e-05; fastest: 3.09944152832e-05`. Moreover, since the function call takes constant time, while the concatenation in the naive method can only take longer as the number  to be concatenated increases, so improveConcat will outperform naiveConcat at some point if `count` is large enough. But when I set `count` larger, improvedConcat takes even longer